# How to remove control char from a payload using Groovy script

Tags: groovy

I am using a Groovy script in SAP CPI application and its getting a payload from source system which has control char 'Backspace', which is create a problem in further steps of csv to xml conversion.
I want to get rid of this Control char before it reached csv to xml step.

Error I am receiving in csv to xml step :

> Invalid white space character (0x8) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity), cause: java.io.IOException: Invalid white space character (0x8) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity)

I have used all the codes below :

```
  body=body.toString().replaceAll("\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}", "")
      body=body.toString().replaceAll("\\\\x08", "")
      body=body.toString().replaceAll("\x8", "")
     /body=body.toString().replaceAll("\\\\x08", "")
        body=body.toString().replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
        body=body.toString().replaceAll("[\u0000-\u001f]", "")
      body=body.toString().replaceAll("\\p{Cc}", "")
```

but none working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simpler replace method:

```
String backspace = '\b' as char
body = body.replace(backspace, "")
```

We should take care that we call replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) and not replace(char, char) because we want to remove the backspace characters and not replace them with another character.

Comment: Thanks. I got where i was making mistake. After replacing the string I was sending to output another String and getting confused. Thanks for your time Vanje.